# Simplest Disco setup (based on the tutorial) fails to start

Tags: python, erlang, disco

I'm new to Disco and just wanted to play around with it. So I tried to setup the most simple instance described in the [documentation](http://disco.readthedocs.org/en/latest/start/install.html). Erlang and Python are installed, I did the Git checkout, ran `make` and started the Disco via `bin/disco nodaemon`. Below you can see the error message when starting the slave. As I'm new to this, I have no glue what might be wrong and how to debug. Any hint would be very appreciated.

```
Eshell V5.10.2  (abort with ^G)
(disco_8989_master@UberAchim)1> 15:20:19.300 [info] Application lager started on node disco_8989_master@UberAchim
15:20:19.324 [info] Application inets started on node disco_8989_master@UberAchim
15:20:19.325 [info] DISCO BOOTS
15:20:19.327 [info] Disco proxy disabled
15:20:19.328 [info] DDFS master starts
15:20:19.331 [info] Event server starts
15:20:19.332 [info] Disco config starts
15:20:19.334 [info] DISCO SERVER STARTS
15:20:19.335 [info] Fair scheduler starts
15:20:19.335 [info] Scheduler uses fair policy
15:20:19.336 [info] Fair scheduler: Fair policy
15:20:19.338 [info] Config table updated
15:20:19.343 [info] Starting node "disco_8989_slave" on "localhost" ("localhost")
15:20:19.357 [info] web server (mochiweb) starts
15:20:19.357 [info] Application disco started on node disco_8989_master@UberAchim
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
15:20:19.640 [info] ddfs_node initialized on disco_8989_master@UberAchim with volumes: ["vol0"]
15:20:19.640 [info] Node failed at disco_8989_slave@localhost on "localhost": {undef,[{#Fun<node_mon.11.72841891>,[],[]}]}
15:20:19.640 [error] Error in process <0.39.0> on node 'disco_8989_slave@localhost' with exit value: {undef,[{#Fun<node_mon.11.72841891>,[],[]}]}


15:20:19.642 [error] Error in process <0.40.0> on node 'disco_8989_slave@localhost' with exit value: {undef,[{#Fun<node_mon.10.72841891>,[],[]}]}


15:20:19.643 [error] Error in process <0.41.0> on node 'disco_8989_slave@localhost' with exit value: {undef,[{lock_server,start_link,[],[]}]}
```

Comment: Have you checked that you can ssh into localhost without it requiring any user input?

Answer (score 2):

The user already had his question answered elsewhere, but I'll go ahead an post the relevant information here to save some search time.

The solution was provided [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/disco-dev/6e8zsw-N13E/xyQenIEzbhkJ) and the underlying issue has already [been fixed](https://github.com/discoproject/disco/commit/531e3546faa0c4dacabf1a0aee35bcad445424a7) by the maintainers of disco.